# How do I return value from this function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a plugin and want to return some value:

```
(function ($) {
    $.SmartMessageBox = function (settings, callback) {
        var SmartMSG = 'hello', Content;

        //some code

        return SmartMSG;

    }
})(jQuery);
```

But the hello is never returned to the caller when I call like this

`console.log($.SmartMessageBox(null,null))`

What am I missing?

Comment: use $.fn.SmartMessageBox ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call like this `console.log($.SmartMessageBox(null,null))` Since it is registered with `$` you should use like above

Comment: you were the quickest.

Answer (score 1):

You probably missed `$` in execution:
$.Smart MessageBox(null, null);

Your code, executed in chrome console:

```
(function ($) {
    $.SmartMessageBox = function (settings, callback) {
        var SmartMSG = 'hello', Content;

        //some code

        return SmartMSG;

    }
})(jQuery);
undefined

$.SmartMessageBox(null, null)
"hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

just tested this in fiddle it works:

```
(function ($) {
    SmartMessageBox = function (settings, callback) {
        var SmartMSG = 'hello', Content;

        //some code

        return SmartMSG;

    }
})(jQuery);


console.log(SmartMessageBox(null,null));
```

[**FIDDLE TEST**](http://jsfiddle.net/PbUY4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
> `

$.fn.SmartMessageBox = function(settings, callback) {
     return "my settings";
};

Alert($.SmartMessageBox());`
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for OP and other readers.